# Unable to start Redis Queue (RQ) worker in Python

Tags: python, redis

I installed Python Redis Queue module using `pip install rq`

When I try to start the worker using `rq` or `rq worker`, it is throwing an error.

```
PYTHONPATH=src REDIS_HOST=localhost rq worker --with-scheduler -u redis://localhost:6379
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jason.bracket\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\rq.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rq\cli\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .cli import main
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rq\cli\cli.py", line 93, in <module>
    @pass_cli_config
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rq\cli\cli.py", line 72, in pass_cli_config
    func = option(func)
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 247, in decorator
    _param_memo(f, OptionClass(param_decls, **option_attrs))
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 2467, in __init__
    super().__init__(param_decls, type=type, multiple=multiple, **attrs)
  File "c:\users\jason.bracket\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 2108, in __init__
    ) from None
ValueError: 'default' must be a list when 'multiple' is true.
make: *** [Makefile:50: start-worker-native] Error 1
```

I am running `Python==3.7` and `rq==1.7.0` on a Windows 10 machine. How can I start a worker? Do I need to configure anything? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: don't hide code in message error .

Answer (score 13):

The problem is the `click` package. You probably have the `8.0.0` version.

Install `click==7.1.2` and it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks. Also https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/1469 suggests this should be resolved in rq==1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to uninstall the version of "click" python module and install the specific version.. but this is the temporary solution.

```
pip uninstall click && pip install click==7.1.2
```

Command support for both Linux and windows

Answer (score 0):

workaround: pin the click to < 8.0.

> `pip install "click>=7,<8"`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not only click but the celery also. However at the time of writing, the following combination works fine -

```
celery==5.2.7
click==8.1.3
rq==1.8.1
```